# No Such User Here VPN/WHM with Mail Routed through Separate Server

Tags: email, dns, vpn, whm

Ok, I am using a VPN on GoDaddy for webhosting. But on one of the websites that I am hosting, the email is handled on a separate VPN.

So I have an A record for domain.com set to the GoDaddy VPN and an A record for mail.domain.com set to the IP of the other domain and several CNAMES pointed to that A record. It's all working beautifully except for one thing....

**Email from other domains on the GoDaddy VPN cannot send to this domain.** So myemail@mydomain.com cannot send to email@separateemailvpn.com

I get error **"No Such User Here"** from my server.

I understand that the GoDaddy VPN is checking for that user locally and not finding it, but I don't know how to make it NOT check for this domain.

I am using WHM/cPanel with Exim and SpamAsassin. Thanks!

Comment: From Reading the question I think you meant VPS, not VPN, and also this would probably be better asked on something like ServerFault / Superuser as it isn't related to programming, which stackoverflow caters to.

Comment: I definitely meant VPS. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the deal is with the downvotes, but here was my solution (probably obvious).

From Linux Terminal:

```
sudo su                     (for admin rights)
nano /etc/localdomains      (erase domain from local domains)
nano /etc/remotedomains     (add domain to remote domains)
```

Now it doesn't check that domain for users locally before it sends it out to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the mail exchanger on the server is relatively easy from WHM too. In WHM left menu, navigate to "DNS Functions >> Edit MX Entry". From there, simply select the domain name you wish to edit, and then select the desired mail exchanger to change the mail routing settings for the domain.

The options are Auto, Local Mail Exchanger, Backup Mail Exchanger, or Remote Mail Exchanger. Set to "Remote Mail Exchanger" and click Save to have WHM update the /etc/localdomains and /etc/remotedomains for you.