# "No Such User Here" Sending from Wordpress to G Suite Email

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, google-workspace

I dont know what the real issue is here but hopefully someone can help.

I am sending emails from a Wordpress site using the plugin [Easy WP SMTP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/) sending through a cpanel email account created. Most of these emails are getting delivered.

I am having one issue sending to our own gsuite email using our own domain. Other gmail addresses(and i would assume gsuite emails) are working fine, it is only our domain that is having issues.

Eg: Woocommerece triggers order emails to both the customer and our gsuite emails. The customers email is delivered, but the mail to our gsuite email is not. Looking at the cPanel > Email > Track Delivery the details of the email are:

```
Recipient:  film@fightthenewdrug.org
Delivery User:  fightthenewdrug
Delivery Domain:    fightthenewdrug.org
Delivered To:   
Router: virtual_aliases
Transport:  fail
Out Time:   Nov 15, 2018, 10:04:10 AM
ID: 1gNL4Y-0003zr-E5
Delivery Host:  
Delivery IP:    
Size:   11.87 KB
Result: No Such User Here
```

And looking at the successful emails:

```
Recipient:  th....@gmail.com
Delivery User:  -remote-
Delivery Domain:    
Delivered To:   th....@gmail.com
Router: dkim_lookuphost
Transport:  dkim_remote_smtp
Out Time:   Nov 15, 2018, 10:03:10 AM
ID: 1gNL3Z-0003zN-TX
Delivery Host:  gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Delivery IP:    64.233.160.26
Size:   11.89 KB
```

The issue is in sending from the site brainheartworld.org to the emails with the domain fightthenewdrug.org. Initially I was using a different SMTP plugin sent form our gmail address @fightthenewdrug.org but we were having quota/limit issues using gsuite gmail.

And just to clarify, I am spelling emails correctly. And it appears to be all emails @fightthenewdrug.org only.

Comment: The recepient address "film@fightthenewdrug.org", is a valid individual gsuit email account or a group? If it's a group, make sure it is not private. i.e. It can receive email out of the domain ids.

Comment: @zipkundan film@fightthenewdrug.org is a valid individual account that can send and receive email to/from any other emails. It also fails to any of our other emails, eg scott@fightthenewdrug.org. Its just sending from this cpanel account to that domain in general...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for `Router: virtual_aliases` the lead me to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786719/no-such-user-here-vpn-whm-with-mail-routed-through-separate-server) and applying that to a cpanel lead me to this [article here](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/understanding-localdomains-and-remotedomains/) which got me figured out.

Because both the sending domain and the receiving domain are hosted on the same VPS, it was trying to bypass the mx lookup(maybe not the correct terminology but the basic idea) and deliver to another domain on the same server locally, but the email was managed by gmail so there was `No Such User Here` for that domain on the local cpanel account.

Under cPanel > Email > Email Routing, if your mail is handled by a remote service, select Remote Mail Exchanger to make sure other accounts on the same server look at the mx records for where to deliver it.

Answer (score 1):

Saved my life. However, i used "Automatically detect configuration" which also seem to work!

SO: under cPanel > Email > Email Routing, selecting **Automatically detect configuration** also works!

Thumbs up!